# OpenGL function in a class

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I'm creating an OpenGL project which includes `ParticleFactory` class to generate particles in a scene.

To achieve that I have created a class:

```
#ifndef PARTICLE_H
#define PARTICLE_H

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include "vertex.h"

#include <shader_s.h>

class ParticleFactory {
    public:
        Shader* shader;
        std::vector<Particle> particles;
        unsigned int VAO, VBO, EBO;
        unsigned int nr_particles;

        ParticleFactory(unsigned int nr_particles, unsigned int color){
            Shader sh("shaders/particle.vs", "shaders/particle.fs");
            shader = &sh;
            this->nr_particles = nr_particles;
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nr_particles; i++) {
                float x = (rand()%200)/100.0 - 1;
                float y = (rand()%200)/100.0 - 1;
                float z = (rand()%200)/100.0 - 1;
                particles.push_back(Particle(glm::vec4(x, y, z, 0.0)));
            }

            glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
            glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
            glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
            glBindVertexArray(VAO);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(base_particle), base_particle, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(base_particle_indices), base_particle_indices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        }

        void draw() {
            shader->use();
            shader->setMat4("model", model);
            shader->setMat4("view", view);
            shader->setMat4("projection", projection);
            shader->setMat4("transform", transform);
            for (int i=0; i<nr_particles; i++) {
                shader->setVec4("offset", particles[i].offset);
                glBindVertexArray(VAO);
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
                particles[i].offset += glm::vec4(0.0f, -0.001f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                if (particles[i].offset.y <= -1.0f) {
                    particles[i].offset.y = 1.0f;
                }
            }
        }
};

#endif
```

My approach here is to first instantiate an object and then call `.draw()` on the main loop but it doesn't seems to work and I don't know why.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  For all we know you could be creating `ParticleFactory` instances without a GL context current or copying them willy-nilly despite the lack of [an appropriate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) ctors/dtor.

Answer (score 1):

Before we even get to the OpenGL part, you're creating a **LOCAL** object (*sh*) and then assigning the address of that to the *shader* member.  At the end of the constructor, *sh* will be deleted, and thus the *shader* member will be pointing to … ?  First, you'll need to use new/delete (or better yet, use std::unique_ptr< Shader >) to make sure that object is still around when you want to use it.

Try that **FIRST**!